# how to set text upside of image in button in android

Tags: android, android-layout, coding-style

i want to set text upside of image in button property.
here is my code for it but i get it text is behind of image which property i have to set ?

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/nav_bar">

<Button
            android:id="@+id/btnHome"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:onClick="onHomeClick"
            android:text="Home"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" 
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/btn_home"
            android:background="@null"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:includeFontPadding="true"
            />
```

Answer (score 1):

use `android:drawableBottom` instead of `android:drawableTop` there.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnHome"
    android:layout_width="wrapcontent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:onClick="onHomeClick"
    android:text="Home"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/btn_home"
    android:background="@null"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:includeFontPadding="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with your `'layout width and height'` that's why your text appears behind the image.

```
<Button android:id="@+id/btnHome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onHomeClick"
        android:text="Home"
        android:gravity="top|center_horizontal" 
        android:drawableBottom="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        ></Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one.instead of specifying width and height better to use wrap_content   property.bcoz in future if u want to change the image that will be automatically fix it.